# Why is the python virtualenv command failing on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I am using Windows 10.  I have been able to install virtualenv using pip.  I installed both Python 3.5 and python 2.7.  That was done from the command line.  I even ran the commands as administrator.  In my path, I have Python 3.5, and the corresponding Scripts folder, occurring prior to the path to python 2.7.  It appears to use the python 3.5 by default.

So, when I ran the command 'virtualenv test' it starts to install a virtual environment but then it fails and I can verify that it did not actually complete the process of creating a virtual environment.  I posted the output of this command at this url: http://pastebin.com/NLZ6tKn1
As an additional note, I am running the command from the D drive and python 3.5 is installed in the Program Files folder on the C drive.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions, 
Bruce

Comment: _sidenote_ python 3.5 comes with its own virtualenv generator, [pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), maybe you can give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug specific to Windows and it happens when you have a space in the directory path where Python is installed.

*This is also why the default installer for Python uses a path like `C:\Python27\` to install Python (for the 2.7 version).*

Your directory for Python is `c:\\program files\\python 3.5` - please uninstall Python and then reinstall it to a path that doesn't have spaces.

Comment: Python 3.5.0 defaults to installing to "Program Files\Python 3.5" for an all-users installation, and 3.5.1 will install to "Program Files\Python35" (in some locales these system directories have no spaces). This is the proper, and properly secured, location to install programs. If there's a bug in virtualenv related to this, the bug needs to be fixed, not the Python installation directory. Until then, only use virtualenv for 2.7. For 3.5, use `py -3 -m venv test` to create a "test" environment.

Comment: I could have just installed it for myself on this computer as no one else would be using this computer to run python apps.  But I'll go ahead and uninstall and then install to a path without spaces.  Python3 used to be installed into a directory on the root of the drive anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: @eryksun: That comment should really be an answer - the `py -3 -m venv test` worked perfectly for me!